# How connect MySQL database to Moqui?

Tags: mysql, moqui

I am new in Moqui and I start learning it so in first step I need configure MySQL database so I read the document in Moqui website and write below code in dev config but the error happen

```
Error initializing webapp context: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class [com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource] not found
```

Do you know what should I do to solve this problem?

```xml
<datasource group-name="transactional" database-conf-name="mysql" schema-name="">
    <inline-jdbc><xa-properties user="root" password="" pinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection="true" serverName="127.0.0.1" port="3306" databaseName="MM" autoReconnectForPools="true" useUnicode="true" encoding="UTF-8"/></inline-jdbc>
</datasource>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi mahdi you can use this config

```xml
<datasource group-name="transactional" database-conf-name="mysql" schema-name="db_name" runtime-add-missing="false" startup-add-missing="true">
    <inline-jdbc jdbc-uri="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db_name?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" jdbc-username="root" jdbc-password="MySqlServerPassword" pool-minsize="2" pool-maxsize="50"/>
</datasource>
```

Answer (score 0):

u can try this solution.It will work for you.

```js
<!-- add datasource elements here to configure databases -->
    <datasource group-name="transactional" database-conf-name="mysql" schema-name="">
        <inline-jdbc jdbc-uri="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/database-name?useSSL=false&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
                     jdbc-username="root" jdbc-password="password" pool-minsize="20" pool-maxsize="50"/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).